# How to add Header to recyclerview in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

after getting successful response, Header added to first position of recyclerview but first item of list not showing. 
list having 5 items but its shows only last 4 items. 
how to show all list items with extra added header in recyclerview.

```
class AllCategoryAdapter(val categoryList : List<AllCategoryBean>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
{
    private val TYPE_HEADER : Int = 0
    private val TYPE_LIST : Int = 1

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

        if(position == 0)
        {
            return TYPE_HEADER
        }
        return TYPE_LIST
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER)
        {
            val header = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cv_all_category_header,parent,false)
            return ViewHolderHeader(header)
        }

        val header = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cv_all_category,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(header)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return categoryList.size + 1
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val listItem : AllCategoryBean = categoryList[position]

        if(holder is ViewHolderHeader)
        {
            holder.tvCategoyName.setText("All Category")
        }

        if(holder is ViewHolder)
        {
            holder.tvCategoyName.setText(listItem.getCategoryName())
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        val tvCategoyName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoyName) as TextView
    }

    class ViewHolderHeader(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        val tvCategoyName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoyName) as TextView
    }

}
```

Comment: Based on your code you should be getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as you are providing a count that is greater than your list size. Can you provide the response you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @**hiddeneyes02** commented in your question, you should be getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

BTW when you increased `categoryList` size by `override fun getItemCount()`, you must also decrease position by one for getting related item in your list when holder is instance of your view, not header.
 
So your `onBindViewHolder` must look like this:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    if (holder instanceof ViewHolderHeader) {
        holder.tvCategoyName.setText("All Category")
    } else if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
        val listItem : AllCategoryBean = categoryList[position - 1]
        holder.tvCategoyName.setText(listItem.getCategoryName())
    }
```

Comment: if position=0, then he will be trying to access an invalid index

Comment: And now you forgot the -1